# Проблемы со звуком

Tags: windows, аудио

Нет звука из обозревателей (опера, мозила, ie). Также, в аське и скайпе я не слышу собеседника, хотя меня все видят и слышат. Установил самый новый флеш, к лайт кодек, с драйверами все ок. В чем проблема?

Стоит windows 7 x64, бук hp dv6 21-67ss.

Comment: на колонках подкрути, то что тебя все слышат - этим микрофон занимается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианта 3:

1. Вы выключили звук на своих колонках.
2. У вас выключен звук в настройках драйвера или в самой винде.
3. У вас не работают колонки, звуковая карта.

Comment: С компа звук есть... В том то и проблема.

Comment: Значит ваш вариант третий - не работают колонки. Или у вас именно с ПО нету звука? Я не понимаю что значит "c компа звук есть", можно как-то более развернуто?

Comment: если нет звуков именно с браузеров, то в 7ке - на значке регулятора громкости, есть пару ползунков отвечающих за звук в конкретных приложения, возможно скручено именно там

Comment: ну это вариант 2 :) всеравно 1 из 3ех, 4ого не дано...

Comment: когда слушаю музыку с компа или смотрю фильмы звук есть... Но в скайпе я не слышу собеседника, в браузерах тоже звука не слышно ( к примеру просмотр роликов и онлайн фильмов)